# how can split string with multiple separators in jquery

Tags: jquery, syntax, split

I want split string when it contain'?' or '.' chars but the pattern don't work and have syntax error, how can fix that? Thank you

```
var str = "Is she sailing a boat?Yes, she is.Are you watching TV?No, I'm looking at the boat."
str = str.split(/.|?/g);
```

Comment: `.` and `?` have a special meaning (like `|`) inside a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You must escape them -> `/\.|\?/g`

Comment: thank you @Andreas it fix my problem, if you want write your comment as answer i will accept that, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` and `?` have a special meaning (like `|`) inside a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
You must escape them with `\`

```
str = str.split(/\.|\?/g);
```